# Create page that both logged and non logged in can view

Tags: php, adodb-php

Hopefully, I explain my issue well enough. I tried searching for a similar question but wasn't able to find anything, I might just be searching for the wrong terms too.

I'm working on a new site,  where users can sign in and modify their profiles,  submit recipes etc.

When I first started on the site, I made it so that users had to sign in to begin. If they are not signed in and go to a profile page they are directed to the homepage.

But now I'm thinking more about the site, and most of the content is hidden because you need to be logged-in to even view it. Which doesn't allow people to share their pages, and this isn't great for SEO either.

How do I create a page where basic content can be viewed.  But if logged in, the extra functionality is there (updating their profile, submit recipes etc).

Here is my config file, which checks to see if they are logged in or not,  and if not redirects to the homepage. I tried just removing the header,  but then I just get blank pages when not logged in.

```
    //Function to check if user is logged in, and if so, return user data as an object
function check_user($secret_key, &$db) {
    if (!isset($_SESSION['userid']) || !isset($_SESSION['hash'])) {
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit;
    } else {
        $check = sha1($_SESSION['userid'] . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . $secret_key);
        if ($check != $_SESSION['hash']) {
            session_unset();
            session_destroy();
           header("Location: index.php");
            exit;
        } else {
            $query = $db->execute("select `id`,`nickname`, `joindate`, `last_active` from `Profile`  where `id`=?", array($_SESSION['userid']));
            $userarray = $query->fetchrow();
            if ($query->recordcount() == 0) {
                session_unset();
                session_destroy();
               header("Location: index.php");
                exit;
            }
            foreach ($userarray as $key => $value) {
                $user->$key = $value;
            }
            $query = $db->execute("update `Profile` set `last_active`=? where `id`=?", array(time(), $user->id));
            return $user;
        }
    }
}
```

Then on the currently protected pages.  I would add this.

```
$userprofile = check_user($secret_key, $db);
```

I still want to be able to use the $userprofile object,  for verifying the user.  But I still want the 'unsecured' content to be viewable and not redirect them to the homepage.

Is there a way to modify what I have, hopefully some of this is savable. I'm using ADODB.

Comment: Well, you'd have to stop redirecting *inside* your login check.  Have your function just check for the user's logged-in state and return that information.  Then let the page that called the function decide what to do with that information.  Redirect, display custom content, etc.  Basically, your function is doing too many things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to rewrite the function in a way that it does not redirect itself anymore. This could be done by rewriting it so it return the user object or `NULL`. If it returns `NULL` the caller can decide whether or not a redirect can happen.

If you do not want to rewrite all your code at once, you can add a new parameter to your function which indicates, whether or not a redirect shall take place in your login check function or not. That parameter should have a default value that lets the function behave as usual.

```
function check_user($secret_key, &$db, $redicrect = TRUE) {
    if (!isset($_SESSION['userid']) || !isset($_SESSION['hash'])) {
        if ($redirect) {
            header("Location: index.php");
            exit;
        }
        return NULL;
    }
    $check = sha1($_SESSION['userid'] . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . $secret_key);
    if ($check != $_SESSION['hash']) {
        if ($redirect) {
            session_unset();
            session_destroy();
            header("Location: index.php");
            exit;
        }
        return NULL;
    }
    //...
}
```